# Do I pick my bard's spells/attacks or do I use preset ones?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I'm wondering if when I'm creating a bard, do I give him the lvl. 1 spell of my choice or do I have to pick the ones that are preset?

Comment: Do you have the Players Handbook?  Did your DM give you a pre rolled bard?

Answer (score 9):

From PHB p.52-53, "Spellcasting":

> You know two cantrips of your choice from the bard spell list. ("Cantrips")
>
> ...
>
> You know four 1st-level spells of your choice from the bard spell list. ("Spells Known of 1st Level and Higher")

Thus *at creation* you look at the bard spell list (PHB p.207) and pick two cantrips and four L1 spells off that list.

As you level up you can learn more and "swap out" L1+ spells you've previously picked, detailed the paragraphs following the quotes.

Comment: Are spells for Bards only able to be used with instruments, or are there a different set of spells for instruments?

Comment: @Liga comments aren't the place for new Q&A. I suggest you either post that question as its own or just pop in to [chat]--there are just-about always 5e experts in there who can and are happy to answer quick little questions like that.